# how to set link text from variable in jade?

Tags: javascript, pug

```
    - each user in users
        - var user = user.username
        p=user
        a(href='users/'+user) link
```

Instead of the link saying "link", I want it to say the username. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `#{variableName}` for variable writes within Jade.

```
a(href="users/" + user) #{user}
```

Comment: I was confused because I was able to do (href='users/'+user) without the #{}, but it works! Thanks! Will accept answer when I can.

Comment: Variables work natively within attribute expansion, but after that, everything is assumed to be the raw text used inside the tag. There, the `#{var}` expansion is required.